# Testing with PEST

Tags: php, laravel, php-pest

I am a complete novice in testing and I wanted to know if someone could guide me on what I'm doing wrong. I want to test the following function in my php laravel project:

```
public static function getFlatSupplierAddress($supplier_address_id): string
    {
        $supplierAddress = Address::findOrFail($supplier_address_id);
        return $supplierAddress->street . " " .
            $supplierAddress->number . " " .
            $supplierAddress->apartment . ", " .
            ($supplierAddress->city ? $supplierAddress->city->name : '') . ", " .
            ($supplierAddress->province ? $supplierAddress->province->name : '') . ", " .
            ($supplierAddress->country ? $supplierAddress->country->name : '');
    }
```

This is my test code:

```
it('returns the formatted supplier address', function () {

        $addressMock = Mockery::mock(Address::class);

        $addressMock->shouldReceive('findOrFail')
            ->with(1)
            ->andReturnSelf(); // Retorna el mismo mock

        $addressMock->shouldReceive('getAttribute')
            ->with('street')
            ->andReturn('Calle');
        $addressMock->shouldReceive('getAttribute')
            ->with('number')
            ->andReturn('456');
        $addressMock->shouldReceive('getAttribute')
            ->with('apartment')
            ->andReturn('Apt 789');
        $addressMock->shouldReceive('city')
            ->andReturn((object)['name' => 'Retiro']);
        $addressMock->shouldReceive('province')
            ->andReturn((object)['name' => 'Buenos Aires']);
        $addressMock->shouldReceive('country')
            ->andReturn((object)['name' => 'Argentina']);

        $expectedAddress = 'Calle 456 , Retiro, Buenos Aires, Argentina';

        $formattedAddress = AddressService::getFlatSupplierAddress(1);

        // Assert
        expect($formattedAddress)->toBe($expectedAddress);
```

Of course I have the problem that I am not using well the Mock since the function returns me a string of an address that it found in the database and it is comparing it with the Mock that I have created.

Comment: Nice example about “useful” gpt, save this.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to mock anything in order to test that

```php
it('returns the formatted supplier address', function () {
    // Arrange
    $address = Address::factory()
      ->for(City::factory())
      ->for(Province::factory())
      ->for(Country::factory())
      ->create();

    // Act
    $formatted = getFlatSupplierAddress($address->id);

    // Assert
    $expected = "{$address->street} {$address->number} {$address->apartment} {$address->city?->name}, {$address->province?->name}, {$address->country?->name}";

    $this->assertEquals($formatted, $expected);
    // or expect($formatted)->toBe($expected);
});
```

---

**Edit** a somewhat more in depth explanation

---

As I commented, `findOrFail` is not actually a method found in `Address`. Laravel does this a lot. It forwards calls to other classes under the hood by using  `__call` or `__callStatic`.

When you do `Address::findOrFail(1)`, it actually calls the underlying `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`'s static `__callStatic('findOrFail', [1])`.

... which in turn just does `(new static)->findOrFail(1)`

... which in turns calls the `Model`'s `__call('findOrFail' [1])`

... which in turn eventually calls the `Model`'s `newQuery()` and returns an `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder`

... which **finally** calls `findOrFail(1)`.

---

And that just covers `findOrFail`. Whenever you call a `Model` 's attributes (`$address->street`, `$address->city->name`, etc), it also forwards the call to other methods via `__call`.

If you really wanted to write this test with mocks and make sure it didn't touch the database, I suppose you could write something like this:

```php
use App\Models\{Address, Country, City, Province};
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

it('returns the formatted supplier address', function () {
    // Arrange
    $address = Address::factory()->make();
    $address->setRelation('city', City::factory()->make());         // Have to set the relations like this
    $address->setRelation('province', Province::factory()->make()); // because the Factory's for method will persist them 
    $address->setRelation('country', Country::factory()->make());   // into the database otherwise
    $address->id = 'fake-id'; // value doesn't really matter.

    // Mock
    $builderMock = Mockery::mock(Builder::class);
    $builderMock->shouldReceive('findOrFail')->with($address->id)->andReturn($address);
    $addressMock = Mockery::mock(Address::class)->makePartial(); // we still need the class's original behavior for some methods.
    $addressMock->shouldReceive('newQuery')->andReturn($builderMock);

    // Act
    $formatted = getFlatSupplierAddress($address->id);

    // Assert
    $expected = "{$address->street} {$address->number} {$address->apartment} {$address->city?->name}, {$address->province?->name}, {$address->country?->name}";

    $this->assertEquals($formatted, $expected);
    // or expect($formatted)->toBe($expected);
});
```

---

As an aside, if you want to test every combiantion of having or not having a `City`, `Province` and `Country` in your `Address`, that's 8 separate cases. You could take advantage of bitwise operations to avoid having to write the same test 8 times.

```php
it('returns the formatted supplier address', function ($i) {
    $address = Address::factory()->create();
    if ($i & 0b001) $address->setRelation('city', City::factory()->make());
    if ($i & 0b010) $address->setRelation('province', Province::factory()->make()); 
    if ($i & 0b100) $address->setRelation('country', Country::factory()->make());
})->with(range(0b000, 0b111))
```

Or, if you don't care about writing to the testing database

```php
it('returns the formatted supplier address', function ($i) {
    $factory = Address::factory();
    if ($i & 0b001) $factory = $factory->for(City::class);
    if ($i & 0b010) $factory = $factory->for(Province::class); 
    if ($i & 0b100) $factory = $factory->for(Country::class);
    $address = $factory->create();
})->with(range(0b000, 0b111))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! What I can't understand is what the Mock is for? I had understood that it was used to simulate calls to the database, or to avoid interacting with it or creating records. once again, thanks!

Comment: Yes, it can be used for that, but usually in tests I just reserve it for when a method depends on something else. Like a call to an external API through the Http facade, or mails/notifications being sent. The reason your mock didn't work is plainly because you mocked the wrong class. `findOrFail` is **not** a method found on the `Address` class.